# How to check if variable exists when set -eu option is set

Tags: bash

In one of my prod scripts, set -eu is set. In this script I want to check if variable exists, but -v and -z option is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
set -o pipefail

INTERNAL="sdkhf"

if [ -v $IINTERNAL ] 
then
    echo "variable doesnt exists"
else
    echo "variable exists"
fi
```

output

```
./script.sh: line 7: IINTERNAL: unbound variable
```

Is there a way to check for variable if it doesn't exist, don't go inside if loop. Also, this is different with question which is plainly asking to check if variable exists. I want to check with option set -eu.

Comment: In your IF condition, don't you have too many "I" in "IINTERVAL" ?

Comment: that extra I is to test non existence of the variable. I just entered it as dummy alphabet to make a new variable.

Comment: Turning the question around: do you really want to use `set -u` if you're fighting this hard against it?

Comment: yes, it is required.

Comment: @LOrD_ARaGOrN Does the accepted answer to the duplicate not work with `-eu`?

Comment: @Biffen Below accepted answer is working but the question suggested to refer to is not having my answer.

Comment: dont know why this question is closed, this is different from what is suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[[ ${var+...} ]]` or `[[ -v var ]]` for testing the existence a variable without triggering an error:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

if [[ ${INTERNAL+1} ]]
then
    echo "variable exists"
else
    echo "variable doesn't exists"
fi

if [[ -v INTERNAL ]]
then
    echo "variable exists"
else
    echo "variable doesn't exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a change that will help (apart from fixing 2'i' in if condition):

No default value :

```
INTERNAL="${INTERNAL:-}"
variable doesnt exists
```

Default Value:

```
INTERNAL="${INTERNAL:-sdkhf}"
variable exists
```

Also, if you set INTERNAL as an env variable, you will notice that gets priority

i.e

```
terminal : export INTERVAL=1
script : INTERNAL="${INTERNAL:-}"
output: variable exists
```

But simply removing $ in if [[ ]] condition is also a solution

```
if [[ -v INTERNAL ]]
```

Note: if [[ ]] and not if [ ]